# Issue Building Flash Video Player (AS3) with Amazon Cloudfront to Stream MP4

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, mp4, amazon-cloudfront

So I have a working Flash player using Cloudfront, AS3, NetConnection & NetStream. Works with a FLV, but I need it to work with MP4s. It connects to the stream, and outputs the following:

```
NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetStream.Play.Reset
NetStream.Play.Start
NetStream.Buffer.Full
```

My presumption is that it is working when looking at these messages, however it doesn't show the video or play any audio. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are streaming and the video does not show, this generally indicates a badly converted MP4.  Here is an article showing how to get the right encoding. 
http://www.miracletutorials.com/converting-video-tutorials-to-streaming-mp4-for-s3-amazon-using-avs-video-converter/

It uses AVS video converter, but these settings are useful for other encoders too.  Just avoid using converters which give you no tweaking options and you will be fine.
Hope this is useful?

I forgot to mention: a badly converted MP4 might play on local computers and even with a download distribution but as soon as you try to stream them, they fail.